# How to stop the tendermint node

Tags: tendermint

I installed tendermint in ubuntu and gave the command tendermint node to run a single node blockchain. I usually close the cmd to kill the process. However I understand that is not the right way of doing it as I have to reset the blockchain everytime i want to continue using it. Please tell me what is the command to stop the node.

Answer (score 2):

- Pressing CTRL-C (which will send SIGINT; sending a signal directly is also possible `kill -2 <PID>`)
- Sending SIGTERM (`kill -15 <PID>`) to a process

will force Tendermint Core to shutdown gracefully